# azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment ignoring parameter file

Tags: terraform, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I am attempting to use terraform and embedded ARM templates to permit creating a simple logic app in Azure. I have the resource block in terraform as:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "templateTEST" {
  name                = "arm-Deployment"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental" 
  template_content    = file("${path.module}/arm/createLogicAppsTEST.json")
  parameters_content = jsonencode({ 
    logic_app_name = { value = "logic-${var.prefix}" }
  })

}
```

and the `createLogicAppsTEST.json` file is defined (just the top few lines as)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "logic_app_name": {
            "defaultValue": "tsa-logic-dgtlbi-stage-001",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
....
```

When deploying and running the first time, ie. creating the logic app resource using terraform and the embedded ARM template, it will create passing the name correctly given the:

```
  parameters_content = jsonencode({ 
    logic_app_name = { value = "logic-${var.prefix}" }
  })
```

however, if I ever run again, terraform appears to ignore the parameters I am passing and goes with the default from the ARM template as:

```
    "logic_app_name": {
        "defaultValue": "tsa-logic-dgtlbi-stage-001",
        "type": "string"
    }
```

I have updated to the latest version of both terraform (0.14.2) and azurerm (2.40.0), yet the issue persists. At present, this kind of makes ARM in terraform problematic given different tiers, dev, test and prod at my company have different prefixes and names ie. prod-, dev-.

Is there a setting to make terraform actually use the parameters I am passing with azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment resource block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I elected to just use the old provider, there is actually an open bug report about this same issue on github

Answer (score 0):

After my validation, you could use the `ignore_changes` field in the nested block lifecycle. It will tell terraform ignore when planning updates to the associated remote object.

For example,

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "templateTEST" {
  name                = "arm-Deployment"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental" 
  template_content    = file("${path.module}/arm/createLogicAppsTEST.json")
  parameters_content = jsonencode({ 
    logic_app_name = { value = "logic-${var.prefix}" }
  })

   lifecycle {
        
        ignore_changes = [template_content,]
    }

}
```

However, in this case, it would be better to declare empty parameters without default values in the embedded ARM templates instead you can pass the real parameters via the `parameters_content`.

For example, declare the parameter like this in the ARM template. This will always use the content of the external parameters.

```
"logic_app_name": {
    "type": "string"
}
```

Comment: I elected to just use the old provider, there is actually an open bug report about this same issue on github

Comment: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8840